# How to associate a model with two or more other models in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to associate some models with at least two other models in an app that I'm developing, but I can't do the association in the controllers.
Here's the code.

**UserModel**

```
public function prices() {
    return $this->hasMany(PriceClass::class);
}
```

**PriceModel**

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belogsTo(ClassOfTheUser::class);
}
public function price_lines() {
    return $this->hasMany(PriceLinesClass::class);
}
```

**AreaModel**

```
public function price_lines() {
    return $this->hasMany(PriceLineClass::class);
}
```

**PriceLinesModel**

```
public function area() {
    return $this->belongsTo(AreaClass::class);
}
public function price() {
    return $this->belongsTo(PriceClass::class);
}
```

How may I do the creation of the Price, if I can't do something like:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $user = UserClass::findOfFail($request->input("user_id"));
        $user->prices()->save(new PriceClass());
        $price = $user->prices()->lastest()->first();
        foreach($request->input("price_lines") as $price_line) {
            $area = AreaClass::findOrFail($price_line["area_id"]);
            $area->price_lines()->save(new PriceLineClass());
            $price_line_instance = $area->price_lines()->lastest()->first();
            $price->price_lines()->save($price_line_instance);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Let's first correct the simple errors. 1) relationship methods must follow the camelCase naming convention => meaning you need to rename `public function price_lines(){}` to `public function priceLines(){}`. 2) you misspelled the `belongsTo()` method on `user()` relationship (you have "belogsTo").

Comment: Assuming you have all the fields nullable in PriceClass and you have scope `scopeLastest($q)` in Price model your code should work as intended.